# question on quadratic equations.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $p, q , r$ be distinct real nos such that 
$ap^2 + bp + c = (\sin(\theta))p^2 +(\cos(\theta))p$
similarly we get a total of three equations if we replace $q$ and $r$ in place of p.
where $a, b, c$ belongs to $\Bbb{R}$

Question is find the max value of:
$(a^2 + b^2)/a^2+ 3ab +5b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the three equations:
$$\begin{align}
ap^2 + bp + c &=& (\sin(\theta))p^2 +(\cos(\theta))p \\
aq^2 + bq + c &=& (\sin(\theta))q^2 +(\cos(\theta))q \\
ar^2 + br + c &=&(\sin(\theta))r^2 +(\cos(\theta))r\end{align}$$

Now we have to keep in mind that $a,b,c,\theta$ are variables and $p,q,r$ are constants and we need to find the max value of $\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+3ab+5b^2}$.
first we can eliminate $c$ by subtractions of the three equations, and as $p,q,r$ are distinct we can simplify by $p-q\neq 0$ and $q-r\neq 0$ to obtain:
$$\begin{align}
a(p+q) + b &=& (\sin(\theta))(p+q) +(\cos(\theta)) \\
a(q+r) + b &=& (\sin(\theta))(q+r) +(\cos(\theta)) \end{align}$$

and hence one can see that $a(p-r)=\sin(\theta) (p-r)$ and again we know that $p-r\neq 0$ hence $a=\sin(\theta)$ and $b=\cos(\theta)$ now it remains to find the max value of:
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+3ab+5b^2}=\frac{1}{1+3\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)+4\cos(\theta)^2} $$

and we can write the denominator as $$1+3\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)+4\cos(\theta)^2=\frac{1}{2}(3\sin(2\theta)+4\cos(2\theta)+6) =\frac{1}{2}(5 \sin(2\theta+\alpha)+6)$$
where $\alpha=\arctan(\frac{3}{4})$.

Finally the maximum value of the given expression is $2$ and the minimum value is $\frac{2}{11}$.

**Comment**
The fact that $a=\sin(\theta)$ and $b=\cos(\theta)$ can be justified by the follwing argument. Let $P(x)=(a-\sin(\theta))x^2+(b-\cos(\theta))x+c$, we observe that  $P$ is a polynomial of degree less that $2$ which have more than $3$ roots (p,q,r) hence $P=0$ and from here we have $a-\sin(\theta)=0$ and $b-\cos(\theta)=0$.

Comment: How do you get the value of $\alpha$

Comment: There is no an explicit value for $\alpha$ (no closed form), but you can compute it approximately using a software program , for instance you can visit : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%283%2F4%29